# How to find number of minimal covers?

Tags: database-design, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

> Consider R(A, B, C, D, E, F, G) be a relational schema with the
>   following functional dependencies: AC → G, D → EG, BC → D, CG → BD,
>   ACD → B, CE → AF.
>  The number of different minimal cover possible
>   are

How do I go about solving the above question ?

What I tried:
--------------------------------------------------------------
My approach to find the number of possible minimal covers was to first use the algorithm (given below) and find the different ways I could find the minimal cover by running through the algorithm (hence giving the number of possible minimum covers). The problem is that I'm not sure how I should consider "a different way to find a minimal cover". For eg:
The algorithm to find the minimal cover (Textbook: "Fundamentals of database systems" - Elmasri, Navathe) :

Input: A set of functional dependencies E.

1. Set F := E.
2. Replace each functional dependency X → {A1, A2, ..., An} in F by the
   n functional dependencies X →A1, X →A2, ..., X → An.
3. For each functional dependency X → A in F
    for each attribute B
   that is an element of X if { {F – {X → A} } ∪ { (X – {B} ) → A} }
       is equivalent to F then replace X → A with (X – {B} ) → A in F.
4. For each remaining functional dependency X → A in F if {F – {X → A}
   } is equivalent to F, then remove X → A from F.

On applying the algorithm, at ACD → B, I found A and D to be extraneous (Replacing ACD → B with C → B gives a set of functional dependencies equivalent to F) at step 3, but I am not sure if I must replace ACD → B with C → B or ACD → B with AC → B or ACD → B with CD → B. Say if I do replace ACD → B with AC → B or CD → B, I'm not sure if replacing ACD → B with AC → B could lead to one possible minimal cover and replacing ACD → B with CD → B could lead to another possible minimal cover.

-------------------------------------------------------------
**Note**:

- "The number of different minimal cover possible" denotes the minimal covers that are possible, given the above relation and functional dependencies.
- Assume that all functional dependencies mentioned in the question are all that hold.

Comment: Those FDs are *not* all that hold. (Which I explained twice.) What the test means & should say is that those FDs form a cover for all the FDs that hold in the schema.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure if I must replace ACD → B with C → B or ACD → B with AC → B or ACD → B with CD → B.

Actually the algorithm must be applied sequentially. So, you can remove either A or D from that dependency, but then you have to check again against the algorithm rule the resulting set of Functional Dependencies.

In fact, if you remove A, for instance, the resulting dependency is `CD → B`, and if you repeat the step, you discover that now in this dependency there are no more extraneous attributes. Similarly, if you remove D, also the resulting dependency `AC → B` does not contain extraneous attributes.

So you can see that, according to the order in which you examine the attributes in this step, you could produce in theory different minimal covers (not always, as in this case).

For what concerns the problem of finding *all* the possible minimal covers, I do not know if there are algorithms or clever techniques to find them. A way could be to try to apply the algorithm by considering the dependencies in all the possible orders, and the left part of the dependencies in all the possible orders, but this of course is an exponential process.

Comment: "check again against the algorithm rule" is not helpful because the algorithm is not clear. One cannot "remove either A or D from that dependency", the dependency is what it is. Yes of course you mean to say something about a related FD & using it and/or the original & F and/or a new value for F in the next steps but neither you nor the algorithm are saying it. That is more of the same kind of unclear writing as the quote. And the question is unclear--it should be clarified & until then closed & downvoted not answered. (But I'm sure you've seen my comments on the question.)

Answer (score 0):

I think answer will be 2

Because following FDs are related to each other so that you can remove either of them
CG --> B
ACD --> B

So minimal cover will contain one of them only hence two minimal covers are possible.